# MATLAB: Sum rows into events per minute

Tags: matlab, time, time-series, cell-array

In MATLAB (R2015b) I have this cell data from a large time-series:

```
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:48'    [ 5]
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:50'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:51'    [12]
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:53'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:56'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:00'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:01'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:12'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:17'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:19'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:21'    [ 4]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:52'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:00'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:05'    [ 3]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:23'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:26'    [ 3]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:36'    [ 3]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:37'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:38'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:43'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:49'    [ 2]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:51'    [ 1]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:55'    [ 1]
```

However, I would like to sum the rows into events per minute (instead of per second), i.e.

```
'01-Jan-2017 09:01:00'    [ 22]
'01-Jan-2017 09:02:00'    [ 12]
'01-Jan-2017 09:03:00'    [ 21]
```

How can I do this for my time-series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) combined with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to sum up all values that occured in the same minute. First we have to convert the first column of date strings into `datetime` objects and then to perform the summation of the second column we convert it to a numeric array using `[data{:,2}]`

```
% Convert the first column to datetime objects and discretize by minute
[inds, edges] = discretize(datetime(data(:,1)), 'minute');

% Sum all values from the same minute
sums = accumarray(inds, [data{:,2}]);

% Create the output cell array of date strings and sums
result = [cellstr(datestr(edges(1:end-1))), num2cell(sums)];

%   '01-Jan-2017 09:01:00'    [22]
%   '01-Jan-2017 09:02:00'    [12]
%   '01-Jan-2017 09:03:00'    [21]
```

**Update**

So it doesn't look like `discretize` works well with `datetime` objects in R2015b, but you could do something like the following where we break the dates into their components, remove the seconds, determine the unique groups and again use `accumarray` to perfom the summation

```
% Break each date into it's components
dv = datevec(data(:,1));

% Set the seconds to 0 so that only minutes are considered
dv(:,end) = 0;

% Find the unique minutes
[vals, ~, inds] = unique(dv, 'rows');

% Sum up the value for each unique minute
sums = accumarray(inds, [data{:,2}]);

% Create the output cell array
result = [cellstr(datestr(vals)), num2cell(sums)];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Still I get "Error using discretize. Too many output arguments." When I use 'help discretize' in MATLAB it only shows examples as 'BINS = discretize(X,EDGES)'. Can I fix this some way? Or is my version (R2015b) too old?

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you! (And time for me to update to a newer version)